# Value of data members not changing inside the Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am using ionic 2 and have a class like the following. i am using the locationServices plugin and don't want to use the ionic native geolocation plugin.

```
export class a{
   location_acquiring:boolean;   
   location_available:boolean;
   constructor(){
        this.location_acquiring=true;
        this.location_available=false;
   }            
   fun(){
        //Here i am using some cordova plugins and setting the location latitude and longitude localstorage variables.
        let self=this;
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled){                                    
            let selfa=self;
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAvailable(function(available){
                let selfb=selfa;
                cordova.plugins.locationServices.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
                    //Now here although project is build without errors. but the values of the variables are not updated.
                    selfb.location_acquiring=false;
                    selfb.location_available=true;
                },function(error){});
            },function(error){});
        },function(error){});
    }
   show_values(){
        console.log(this.location_acquiring);
        console.log(this.location_available);
    }
}
```

The variable changes inside the locationServices plugin are not reflected inside the class variables.

Output of the `show_values()` function

true
false

Comment: Untested and might be unrelated, but for google maps API, you need to run the some call backs inside zone.js explicitly. What if you try injecting `private __zone: NgZone` (NgZone lives in angular/core) in the constructor, and then do: 
`this._zone.run(() => {
                   selfb.location_acquiring=false;
                   selfb.location_available=true;
                });`

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to the `let self = this;` technique anymore, just use TypeScript's lambda syntax `() => {}` instead of an anonymous function in order to access `this` (your instance of class "a") deep within the lambdas.

Then, make sure you're checking if an error is happening within the Cordova plugin calls (e.g. by outputting the error to the debug console) and hence why your success callback code is never being executed.

Try with the following code:

```
export class a{
  location_acquiring: boolean = true;
  location_available: boolean = false;

  fun(){
    //Here i am using some cordova plugins and setting the location latitude and longitude localstorage variables.
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled((enabled) => {
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAvailable((available) => {
            cordova.plugins.locationServices.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
                //Now here although project is build without errors. but the values of the variables are not updated.
                this.location_acquiring=false;
                this.location_available=true;
            }, function(error){
              console.error('[watchPosition]', error);
            });
        }, (error) => {
          console.error('[isLocationAvailable]', error);
        });
    }, (error) => {
      console.error('[isLocationEnabled]', error);
    });
  }

  show_values(){
    console.log(this.location_acquiring);
    console.log(this.location_available);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.